# Accidental plumbing leak. How bad is this? What should I have my contractor do?

Tags: plumbing, leak, remodeling

I'm remodeling my 2nd floor bathroom and we are in the demolition phase. My contractor's plumber accidentally turned the main water on without checking the bathroom hot/cold lines. They were not capped. Water flooded into the floor  and started spilling out of the ceiling light fixtures on the 1st floor. I would say the water was on for about 60 seconds full blast. It appears there is water coming out of multiple places on the first floor.

**[Video](https://youtu.be/VPpu03FUIso)**

The above video was taken about 5 minutes after the water had been turned off. I have another video showing the leak right as it happened and it shows much more water flow.

I'm assuming we should take down the drywall in any wet areas to let it dry. The plumber said it wasn't a big deal and it will dry on its own. What should I do? How bad is this?

Comment: How quickly is it drying?  How long have things been wet for?  Where is the water going?

Comment: Ofc the plumber said it wasn't a big deal. What else would he say? He's on the hook to fix whatever trouble he's caused ...

Answer (score 5):

I'd give the contractor a chance to fix things. Your house isn't going to collapse into mold and mush over one event, but you do want to be sure that things are thoroughly dry and that there's no sagging of the drywall or severe warping of lumber.

I'd expect the contractor to have fans going in several places, especially in the ceiling joist cavities. I'd expect them to express real concern and a desire to rectify the situation.

Comment: The last paragraph of this is key

Answer (score 1):

If there is no sagging of the sheetrock and no discoloration to the entire area it may be ok. I would wait a few days as I have seen leaks that did dry out with no problems, I have also seen ceilings collapse (the sheetrock) close to a week later. Any discoloration would be a pull it out trigger for me.